# Is this my code or Firebase code causing this leak?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, firebase, leakcanary

I am getting a lot of memory leaks in an application I created.   I created a very simple app to reproduce the problem.  This application just makes a reference to the FirebaseDatabase and sets up a ChildEventListener.  When the user clicks the button it adds a record to the database, and starts a new activity which does System.gc().

Pressing the button multiple times will cause Leak Canary to generate a dump.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference dbRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    dbRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("leak");
    dbRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.btn_leak).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dbRef.child(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).setValue("Yes");
            Intent leakIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LeakActivity.class);
            startActivity(leakIntent);
        }
    });

}
```

}

LeakActivity.java:

```
public class LeakActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.leak);

        System.gc();
    }
}
```

Due to the post limit, the leak canary log is [here.](https://utopiagps.com/leak.log)

Am I doing something wrong in my code, or is this related to Firebase?

**EDIT:**  @qbix's answer seemed to work.   For others, here is the working version of MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference dbRef;
private ChildEventListener dbListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    dbRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("leak");
    dbListener = getDbListener();
    dbRef.addChildEventListener(dbListener);

    findViewById(R.id.btn_leak).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dbRef.child(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).setValue("Yes");
            Intent leakIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LeakActivity.class);
            startActivity(leakIntent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    dbRef.removeEventListener(dbListener);
    super.onStop();
}

private ChildEventListener getDbListener(){
    return new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used LeakCanary, so this is just an educated guess.

`ChildEventListeners` need to be [unregistered](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#detach_listeners) when they are no longer needed.  Often listeners are added and removed in activity lifecycle methods, such as `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()`.  Instead of creating an anonymous listener, create an object of that type and remove it using [Query.removeEventListener()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#removeEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener)) when no longer needed to see if that eliminates the leak report.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is better to add/remove listeners within the onStart()/onStop() or the onCreate()/onDestroy() callbacks respectively.

If a listener was added in onCreate() and removed in onStop() there could occur a situation when an activity will be restored without of calling the onCreate() but with calling of onStart() and listener will not be set.

https://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png